# how to load image from sdcard into pager adapter?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-pageradapter

I am new to android development, i want to load image from either internal storage/pictures/forldername or sdcard/pictures/foldername with swipe feature as galley. All images should be displayed as swipes. Can I havae an example of some what.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for fast and efficient image loading.

```
String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foder_name/locationtoyourimage.png";

 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
    .load(path)
    .centerCrop()
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start creating a example of your attempts. You can start creating a `ImageView` and load into app.

To load the image insert into your code:

```
private Bitmap getImage(String imageName) {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root+"/pictures/forldername/" + imageName + ".jpg");
}
```

Into your `onCreate`, put the picture like:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getImage);
```

Insert permission in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```